# Как сделать отправку логов с помощью php, если значения переданы через js

Tags: javascript, php, html, axios

В js вообще не разбираюсь, просьба помочь.
С помощью js генерируется форма с вводом имени и номера, и значения передаются на sender.php, что нужно вписать в php файл чтобы эти значения обработались как переменные?

```
var e = this;
                    if (null !== localStorage.getItem(r + "usermail").replace(/ /g, "").match(/\d/g)) {
                        var s = encodeURI(localStorage.getItem(r + "usermail").trim()),
                            a = localStorage.getItem(r + "username") ? encodeURI(localStorage.getItem(r + "username")) : encodeURI("noname");
                        o.post(r + "/php/sender.php?offer=" + r.replace(/\//g, "") + "&number=" + encodeURI(s.replace(/ /g, "")) + "&name=" + encodeURI(a)).then((function (t) {})).catch((function (t) {
                            e.errorMessage = t.message, console.error("There was an error with Axios!", t)
                        }))
                    }
                },
```

Также код в sender.php (сейчас не работает)

```
<?php
$mail= $_GET['usermail'];
$name = $_GET['username'];

$token = 'token';
$chatid = 'id';

if (isset($_GET['usermail'])) {
    
$send = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chatid}&parse_mode=html&text=Получена новая заявка!%0A Почта: {$mail}%0AФИО: {$name}%0A");
}
?>
```

Comment: `/php/sender.php?offer=` +  `&number=` + `&name=` any idea? и с чего бы оно не работало, прям вот странно... и если этот php код будет на реальном сайте - я вам сочувствую заранее :)

Comment: Что исправить нужно?

Comment: Если я скажу всё - вы не поверите, но это так. на данный момент любой кто обратится к скрипту на прямую - будет слать вам сообщение. если кто то решит над вами пошутить - пара тысяч сообщений за пару минут - не составит труда.

Comment: Я понимаю что нужно заменить php часть, но не знаю как её связать с js

Comment: А на этот вопрос я в первом комментарии ответил, вам нужно вообще освежить базовые знания, что такое $_GET например :)

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю что это... Я не знаю что нужно писать чтобы связать js с php, я понимаю каждую строку в php скрипте, но не понимаю js

Comment: Обьясните мне что такое $_GET и откуда там появляются данные :) как зная эту информацию вы не можете сопоставить 2 и 2? Прочтите вот это, надеюсь придет понимание о чем первый комментарий... https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php

Comment: Get запрос берёт инфо с адресной строки, это здесь не при чём, я не знаю как связать его с вышеуказаным js скриптом, возможно те данные нужно каким то другим выражением обработать, я в посте указал итоговую цель